# Oracle Migration Upgrade 11g to 12c New Server

Tags: oracle, migration, upgrade

I'm fairly new to Oracle databases and have been tasked with assessing the implications of upgrading our application's database from 11g to 12c.

I have managed a successful in-place upgrade but a number of stakeholders will be looking to upgrade to new hardware so I need to access the viability of a migration upgrade.

Is it possible to migrate the current active database to a fresh installation of 12c and which would be the most effective method for this?

Comment: As always, it depends, there is no silver bullet. You did not provide enough information for us to recommend the most effective method. Data Pump is the easiest for people new to Oracle databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `expdp` and `impdp` utility by Oracle for migration of database from 11g to 12c.

First of all we will use expdp utility to export the whole database into a dumpfile (.dmp) by issuing the following command:

```
expdp system/password@db11g full=Y directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=DB11G.dmp logfile=expdpDB11G.log
```

Here, FULL parameter indicates that the whole database will be exported
      Directory --> The directory on server in which you want to place the dumpfile
      DUMPFILE --> The name of dumpfile
      LOGFILE --> The name of logfile (that logs the status of export process)

After the export is done successfully you will get something like:
`Job "SYSTEM"."SYS_EXPORT_FULL_01" successfully completed at 10:35`

Now, your whole database is stored in a dumfile(.dmp) in the 'DIRECTORY' mentioned in the expdp command.

We will now start import of the database into 12c database with the help of impdp utility.

```
impdp system/password@db10g full=Y directory=TEST_DIR dumpfile=DB11G.dmp logfile=impdpDB12c.log
```

*Before starting import you might need to transfer the dumpfile to the new server (i.e. 12c)

After import has been successfully completed you will get successfull completion message.

Reference link --> https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g

Happy Migration !!

Comment: It's worth noting that datapump can be done across the network, avoiding the creation and transfer of massive dump files

Comment: @AndrewBrennan Yes absolutely correct :)

Comment: As I am working with a completely fresh 12c installation on the destination server I assume that I will need to create a new database instance into which I will import the dumpfile. Does this new instance need to be set up in any way to match the source database or can I simply create a new instance and import into it, allowing the import tool to construct the database for me?

Comment: Sorry my bad. I am late for reply. Thank you for marking this answer. I hope it has helped you. You can create a similar instance otherwise a new instance will work fine before import :)  yes the import utility will create the new database.